# Table cannot be created through hibernate. Though my application runs without errors

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Trying to auto create mysql table through my application. Though i dont get any errors when running the app.. no table is created

my model class

```
package user;

import jakarta.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false, name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false, name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Not sure if doing anything wrong in the application.properties file
I think i got the right annotations in the User class.
I donnot get any errors while running the application, but no tables are created.

Comment: constructor missing otherwise LGTM.

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad thanx for the response. I had to move the Model class to the package with the main application class. It worked. thanks again.